# jQuery: animate decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a number from 0 to 36.6, but currently having no luck as it's just rounding up the end value to 37, as you can see in this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/0f3hxej8/

Necessary markup below:
HTML

```
<div id="el"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
// Animate the element's value from x to y:
  $({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 36.6}, {
      duration: 3000,
      easing:'swing', // can be anything
      step: function() { // called on every step
          // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
          $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
      },
      complete:function(){
          $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
      }
  });

 function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
    }
    return val;
  }
```

Ideally I'd like it to animate up through decimals too, e.g. 35.9, 36.0, 36.1, 36.2 etc etc. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well it's rounding the values because you've got explicit calls to `Math.round()` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round to one decimal place by multiplying by ten before rounding, and then dividing by ten afterwards.

```
Math.round(this.someValue * 10) / 10)
```

As shown in your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f3hxej8/2/).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the [`Math.round10`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round#Decimal_rounding) function provided on MDN. You can simply change your code to:

```
 $('#el').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round10(this.someValue, -1)));
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0f3hxej8/3/)**